# Audio timestamp not accurate in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, google-chrome, audio

I am building a web app which includes an audio element, the source of which is a ~ 1 hour long .mp3 file hosted locally. When I click the seekbar to skip to a point in the audio (for instance 00:01:00) the time stamp goes to 1:00 and audio begins to play, but the audio is not the actual portion which is at 1:00 but rather a different portion from the file (in this case it plays the sound from 00:00:12). The same issue occurs when I set `currentTime` programmatically.

In short, **In `<audio>` elements in Chrome, setting `currentTime` works, but the audio which begins to play is not the actual audio which one would hear if listening to the file naturally from the beginning.**

This does not occur in Firefox. The issue occurs in portions of the .mp3 which have already been loaded by the client. The file is being served via an Express.js server (by create-react-app).

I have attempted to resolve the issue in the following ways.

- I have confirmed that the .mp3 file is Constant Bit-Rate (using [mp3checker.exe](https://checkmate.gissen.nl/))
- I have verified that the response headers include `Accept-Ranges: bytes` and `Content-Range: bytes 0-53497347/53497348` (Some have suggested including these headers to resolve similar issues, not sure if I should do anything besides confirming that these headers are present)
- Added `type="audio/mpeg"` attribute to `<source />` tag.

Edit: The issue does not occur when the entire file is preloaded. It also does not occur when the .mp3 file is cut into individual shorter length files. However I do not believe that either of these solutions are applicable.

None of these efforts have resolved the issue. Not sure if the problem is the file, the server, or the browser.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try setting preload to metadata? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if the file itself was corrupt, although I am not sure in which way. The file was created through concatenating several .mp3 files using a recursive read/write stream in node.js. This method apparently caused aspects of file to become corrupt, such that different players interpreted the file's metadata differently. If anybody can shed light upon why concatenating .mp3 files in such a way can cause issues, it would be informative.